# Registering a copyright for a web-app: what type?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, internet

I'm registering a copyright for a draft of a web-application I'm developing. I shared it with a potential defactor too soon and I want to at least put something down. In the "type of work" section, the options are: "Literary Work," "Work of Visual Arts," "Sound Recording," "Work of the Performing Arts," "Motion Picture/AV work," and "Single Serial Issue".

It's a web application for visualizing and interacting with data in a new and unique way. Would this be a Work of Visual Arts? I know people register websites but I haven't found the answer to this question anywhere.

Thanks! I know that this whole thing might be considered a waste of time, but it seems like a minimal effort for a large potential upside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Software is a literary work under copyright law

By the way, copyright exists automatically from the moment of creation without needing to register. Copyright is not patent law.

Comment: Thanks @Dale! I will also be doing a patent. Am I correct in assuming that there should be no issue with doing both?

Comment: You can’t do a patent - you don’t have an invention

Comment: is it feasible that a sufficiently novel interface would be patentable?

Comment: @IsaacHowenstine there are user interface patents.  But don't forget that the patent office's granting a patent doesn't say much about whether the patent will survive a court challenge.

Comment: @phoog interesting. Thank you!